# How do I access separate points/sections on a single image in html/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am learning to develop mobile applications, quite in the initial phase.

This query is not related to mobile but more to html/css/js.(for

I intend to make a simple game, where a picture is seen, a few options are available and the user can drag and drop these options onto the image.
eg. There is an image of a plant > options are #leaf #stem #flower #bud
The user must drag and drop the correct option to the correct place on the image to get points. i.e Drag the #leaf option onto the leaf of the plant.

Now my problem is the image, the separation of these points, I can't figure out how to do it.

**Query in short: How do I access separate points/sections on a single image in html/js for above purpose?**

**Query (longer version)**
I did a little search and realised I can slice the image and recreate it using multiple images, I tried this, it sort of works but it has a a lot of drawbacks:

1)More images mean more space, combined size of the split images was about 1.5x the original image(this is just splitting it into 4 images)

2)For a complex picture, the number of images to slice into is large and hard to manage in css(n00b==me) as they don't just need to be split into a simple X*Y grid but a much more complex split depending on the object in the image.(realised when I was trying to do a simple cell structure img)

3)More images also means more http requests(in case the app is WebView based) which will increase loading time.

It just seemed liked too much of a hassle, there must be a better way.

Then I saw css sprites , I dont need to combine my images like sprites are intended for, rather the reverse. Just access parts of my pre-existing image, as separate objects.I haven't tried this(working on it) and and I haven't seen this being done either, or maybe its being done and I'm not seeing.

Please help guys, my problem is quite simple(I think) , I think I'm just not getting the correct google search terms.

If anybody has any ideas,links, resources and also any clarifications as I may not have put up my problem as clearly as I'd like to, please do reply.

regards,
Rahul Agarwal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to place transparent divs over the main image using absolute position and fixed dimensions. Those divs will be assosiated to the possible options, and when a user drops an option over some specific div, you'll know what points to give.

Little demo using two divs and an animated scaling to show that the positioned divs will scale according to their parent:

http://jsfiddle.net/VK3A8/

fiddel with image:
http://jsfiddle.net/8qLFc/4/

Comment: The image needs to be scalable for different display sizes so would this approach still be feasible, as of now I am using 
img {
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;}
So that the the image is scalable

Comment: @RahulAgarwal Pretty much yes, the only problem would be that all positioning, width and height values would have to be percentage values. But this way, they would scale with their parent div.

Comment: Hey I tried your idea out, the problem is that if I place the image inside the div , it refuses to scale because the div does not scale automatically
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext.css" />
<div id="foo">
<img src="pcell1.png" alt=" " >
    <div id="bar"></div>
<div id="bar1"></div>
</div>

Comment: @RahulAgarwal Can you provide a test-link. Without seeing your test-code, it's really hard to tell how to help you.

Comment: Yes here it is http://jsfiddle.net/8qLFc/3/
Sorry I'm new at stackoverflow
As you can imagine from the image what I aim to do, specific areas in the image point to specific parts(eg nucleus)

I am quite an amateur(currently interning and this is the project I have been given), the image resizes here using the animate command, but I want automatic resizing, if this code is used without the js and I resize my browser, the image doesn't resize(it should because of the img{} css code is what I am assuming, I dont mind using another technique as well.
And thanks for all the help

Comment: I think I have to make use of Image Maps and hotspots, something like this http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/imagemap.shtml .Problem here too is the scaling aspect, the areas can't be defined as %

Comment: @RahulAgarwal I've updated your fiddle, have look here: http://jsfiddle.net/8qLFc/4/    The main problem was, that there have been absolute dimensions on the outer div (`#foo`), so the image will only assume those dimensions. If you remove them, the outer div, and thus the image, will scale with the available viewport width. (on a side note, the `animate` was just for demonstration, no need to use this for your problem).